# I need to put parentheses and numbering before the values in the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I try to put parentheses at the beginning and end of the line

Input:

First Iteration

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Second Iteration

```
4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6
```

I need to put before each value in the field, a number from 1 to 3 in the first iteration, in the next 4-6 and thus continue after the iterations.
As shown below

```
(11 21 31)
(12 22 32)
(13 23 33)

(44 54 64)
(45 55 65)
(46 56 66)
```

I tried adding it but it was not effective for my program

This is my full code:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in list(lines):
    w = i[3:]
    w = ', '.join(w.split())
    #print(w)
    #time.sleep(1)
    y = i[2]
    y=int(y)+1
    #print(y)
    c1=np.array([w])
    c1 = [int(i) for i in c1[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
    c1=np.array([c1]*3)
    c1=np.transpose(c1)
    a=str(c1).replace("[",'')
    a=str(a).replace("]",'')
    a=str(a).replace("\n ",'\n')
    print('\n')
    print(a)
```

demofile.txt is:

```
<=1 1 2 3
<=1 4 5 6
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Yes, of course, I will adjust the question

Answer (score 0):

something like so?

```py
num = 50

#plain lists
x = [[ [x+i]*3 for i in range(3)] for x in range(0,num, 3)]

print(x)

#with tuples
x = [tuple([ tuple([x+i]*3) for i in range(3)]) for x in range(0,num, 3)]

print(x)
```

```py
[[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]], [[6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8]], [[9, 9, 9], [10, 10, 10], [11, 11, 11]], [[12, 12, 12], [13, 13, 13], [14, 14, 14]], [[15, 15, 15], [16, 16, 16], [17, 17, 17]], [[18, 18, 18], [19, 19, 19], [20, 20, 20]], [[21, 21, 21], [22, 22, 22], [23, 23, 23]], [[24, 24, 24], [25, 25, 25], [26, 26, 26]], [[27, 27, 27], [28, 28, 28], [29, 29, 29]], [[30, 30, 30], [31, 31, 31], [32, 32, 32]], [[33, 33, 33], [34, 34, 34], [35, 35, 35]], [[36, 36, 36], [37, 37, 37], [38, 38, 38]], [[39, 39, 39], [40, 40, 40], [41, 41, 41]], [[42, 42, 42], [43, 43, 43], [44, 44, 44]], [[45, 45, 45], [46, 46, 46], [47, 47, 47]], [[48, 48, 48], [49, 49, 49], [50, 50, 50]]]

[((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)), ((3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5)), ((6, 6, 6), (7, 7, 7), (8, 8, 8)), ((9, 9, 9), (10, 10, 10), (11, 11, 11)), ((12, 12, 12), (13, 13, 13), (14, 14, 14)), ((15, 15, 15), (16, 16, 16), (17, 17, 17)), ((18, 18, 18), (19, 19, 19), (20, 20, 20)), ((21, 21, 21), (22, 22, 22), (23, 23, 23)), ((24, 24, 24), (25, 25, 25), (26, 26, 26)), ((27, 27, 27), (28, 28, 28), (29, 29, 29)), ((30, 30, 30), (31, 31, 31), (32, 32, 32)), ((33, 33, 33), (34, 34, 34), (35, 35, 35)), ((36, 36, 36), (37, 37, 37), (38, 38, 38)), ((39, 39, 39), (40, 40, 40), (41, 41, 41)), ((42, 42, 42), (43, 43, 43), (44, 44, 44)), ((45, 45, 45), (46, 46, 46), (47, 47, 47)), ((48, 48, 48), (49, 49, 49), (50, 50, 50))]
```